# Sed regex and back reference

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I want to extract hostname from the netgroup of format (hostname,,). I used the following sed commands. it seems none of them works. Could anyone point me to the right regex construction? Thanks.

```
bash-3.2# ypcat -k netgroup|grep '^gridprod2 '|sed 's/(\([a-zA-Z0-9]*\),,)/\1\n/g'
gridprod2 (sbpsvrso766,,) (sbpsvrso767,,) (sbpsvrso768,,) (sbpsvrso769,,) (sbpsvrso461,,) (sbpsvrso462,,) (sbpsvrso463,,) (sbpsvrso464,,) (sbpsvrso465,,) (sbpsvrso466,,) (sbpsvrso467,,)  (sbpsvrso468,,) (sbtorsvr569,,) (sbpsvrwm841,,) (sbpsvrwm842,,) (sbpsvrwm843,,) (sbpsvrwm844,,) (sbpsvrwm845,,) (sdpsvrso804,,)

bash-3.2# ypcat -k netgroup|grep '^gridprod2 '|sed 's/(\([:alnum:]*\),,)/\1\n/g'
gridprod2 (sbpsvrso766,,) (sbpsvrso767,,) (sbpsvrso768,,) (sbpsvrso769,,) (sbpsvrso461,,) (sbpsvrso462,,) (sbpsvrso463,,) (sbpsvrso464,,) (sbpsvrso465,,) (sbpsvrso466,,) (sbpsvrso467,,)  (sbpsvrso468,,) (sbtorsvr569,,) (sbpsvrwm841,,) (sbpsvrwm842,,) (sbpsvrwm843,,) (sbpsvrwm844,,) (sbpsvrwm845,,) (sdpsvrso804,,)
```

Comment: are the gridprod2 lines the lines coming out of ypcat? If so this seems to work fine when I do it

Comment: What version of `sed`? The first command works fine for me, the second does, too, if you change `[:alnum:]` to `[[:alnum:]]`.

Comment: Hi, when I copied the commands from what I posted, they worked. I can't believe it:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `grep -oP` with [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) instead:

```
echo "gridprod2 (sbpsvrso766,,) (sbpsvrso767,,) (sbpsvrso768,,) (sbpsvrso769,,) (sbpsvrso461,,) (sbpsvrso462,,) (sbpsvrso463,,) (sbpsvrso464,,) (sbpsvrso465,,) (sbpsvrso466,,) (sbpsvrso467,,)  (sbpsvrso468,,) (sbtorsvr569,,) (sbpsvrwm841,,) (sbpsvrwm842,,) (sbpsvrwm843,,) (sbpsvrwm844,,) (sbpsvrwm845,,) (sdpsvrso804,,)" \
| grep ^gridprod2 | grep -oP '(?<=\()[^,\)]*'
```

Output:

```
sbpsvrso766
sbpsvrso767
sbpsvrso768
sbpsvrso769
...
```

And probably what's more precise is

```
grep -oP '(?<=\().*?(?=,,\))'
```

Answer (score 0):

An `awk` version:

```
awk -F, 'NR>1 {print $1}' RS="(" file
sbpsvrso766
sbpsvrso767
sbpsvrso768
sbpsvrso769
.....
```